# Is it a property of any vector norm on $\mathbb{C}^n$?

Tags: normed-spaces

That $||e_1||$ = 1.  Where $e_i$ is the standard basis for $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If $||.||$ is a norm, $2\cdot||.||$ is also a norm and leads to a counterexample.

Comment: But when you change the norm ,  $e_i$ change too. I mean $e_i$ is the standard basis , $||e_i||=1$ is a part of the definition of it.

Comment: @Syuizen Why? By "standard basis for $\mathbb{C}^n$", OP seems to imply the set $\{(1,0,0,0,...),(i,0,0,...), (0,1,0,...) ...\} $.

Otherwise, I don't see how you can specify what is THE standard basis of any norm.

Comment: The standard basis is defined as the set of linear-independently orthonormal unit elements.

Comment: @Syuizen Okay. Then tell me the standard basis of the tangent plane at the point $(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}, -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}, \frac{\sqrt{3}}{3})$ of the sphere.

The point is: you can construct an orthonormal basis (for example, by Gram-Schmidt). This does not mean there is a standard one. Making "the standard basis" be "the set of linear-independent orthonormal unit elements" is intrinsically a ill-defined concept, since what you describe is non-unique and there is no way in general to canonically produce one such object.

Comment: Exactly , for Riemannian Geometry , the standrad one is vague. Therefore , we just consider the "natural basis" or the local basis consists of tangent vectors. I guess we can stop argue anymore , since the name is not the key issue.